# how to display two javascript variables with the append method of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

If I try to display content with this piece of code, I ve got the expected result :

```
$("#checkbox_list").append($("<li/>", {id: "medias_bloc_"+id, html: table }) ); //a HTML a classical html table is appended
```

But if I try to add another js variable which contains some html element like this:

```
$("#checkbox_list").append($("<li/>", {id: "medias_bloc_"+id, html: table + input }) );
```

then, there is just the input html appearing (a basic html input) and instead of the table I ve got this: [object Object]

How can I fix that ?

edit : thx for the answers this is the result for both console.log of the variables:

```
Object[table.add_table] //console.log(table)

<input name="cat" type="hidden" value=3105 />//console.log(input)
```

Okay so there's one string and one object and I can't concatenate then...

Comment: But what are `table` and `input`?

Comment: `table` and `input` are both objects? `object + object` will always result in `[object Object]`

Comment: That would suggest that `table` is some kind of object, so don't (you can't) use concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append objects this way. use `.Append()`

When you try to add an operator between objects in `html` property, it concatenate their type names i.e `[object][object] [object][object]`

```
$("#checkbox_list").append($("<li/>", {id: "medias_bloc_" + id}).append(table).append(input) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mentioned what `table` and `input` are.

If `table` and `input` are jQuery objects, you can't simply concatenate them. It would be good solution for strings.

Answer (score 1):

As you can't concatenate with objects, you need to either append one by one (see PSL's answer), or get the html of each object and concatenate that.

```
$("#checkbox_list").append($("<li/>", {id: "medias_bloc_"+id, html: $(table).html() + $(input).html() }) );
```

I would go with PSL's answer, appending one by one.

Comment: Seems like a bit of a leap to go from "`table` is some kind of object" to "passing it to the jQuery function will give nice, predictable results".

Comment: as it worked with just `table` in his first example I would assume it's either a dom element or a string containing html.